# Retrieve Related Data (Multi-Level)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three classes:

1. **Country**.
2. **District**.
3. **Province**

   ```
   public class Country
   {
       public Country()
       {
           Districts = new HashSet<District>();
       }

       public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; private set; }
   }

   public class Ditrict
   {
       public Ditrict()
       {
           Provinces = new HashSet<Province>();
       }

       public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Province> Provinces { get; private set; }
   }

   public class Province
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

What I need to accomplish is how to include all **Provinces**, **Districts** (Even if there is no **Provinces**), **Country** (Even if there is no **Districts**) in one command using Ling.

The reason is that I am going to use DevExpress Grid, so the user can see the **Country** and add a new **District**, and can see the **District** and add a new **Province**.

My all attempts failed, because what I get is the **Country** that have **Disctrict** and **District** that have **Province**.

Btw, I am using:

- VS 2015
- EF Core
- MS SQL 2016

**[Solution]**

After many attempts and searching, I discovered that I need to use **.ThenInclude** to the third level **Provinces**. Like:

```
Countries = dbContext
                .Countries
                .Include(c => c.Districts)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Provinces)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice if you could send us what you have tried. Roughly speaking you can use `Include` to eager load dependent entities and collections. If you query the chain of entities starting from `Country` it will retrieve all the countries even if they don't have `District`s:

```
using (var dbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
    return dbContext.Countries
        .Include(c => c.Districts.Select(d => d.Provinces))
        .ToList();
}
```

I guess the reason you retrieve countries only if they have districts, etc, is because your query starts from the other end of the chain (`Province`) rather than starting from `Country` as above.

Comment: What I tried did not compile at all. Anyhow, I tried what you suggest, but I got error during running "Additional information: The property expression 'c => {from District d in [c].Districts select [d].Provinces}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data"

Comment: @AbdurahmanAlmatrodi Hi Abdurahman, if my answer didn't help you, please create an answer yourself with the same content as you put in the update of the question, and then mark it as answer. Thanks.